# Regular expression to match balanced parentheses or none parantheses

Tags: javascript, regex, parentheses

I need a regular expression to test string , either string do not contain parentheses or it contain balanced parentheses. The expression I am using only check it contain balanced parentheses or not . If I give string without parentheses it return false.
I want it return true if it do not contain any parentheses

```
function func(str) {

 let reg = /\([^()]*\)/;
  console.log(reg3.test(str))
  console.log(str.match(reg3))
}

func("33")
func("1(1)6")
func("11)6")
```

The problem is it give false if I do not give any parentheses , I need to write that it return true if string do not contain parentheses nd false if string contain unbalanced parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all substrings between closest parentheses, and then check if a string contains a `(` or `)` char.

```js
function remove_nested_parens(s) {
    let new_s = s.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)/g, "");
    return new_s == s ? s : remove_nested_parens(new_s);
}
const texts = ["no parens", "XX(DD(D)DDDD)XXX", "(DD(D)DDDD))XX"];
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', !/[()]/.test(remove_nested_parens(text)) )
}
```

The recursive `remove_nested_parens` function removes parenthesized substrings and `!/[()]/.test(remove_nested_parens(text))` checks if the result contains `(` or `)`.